# How to use strpos() insted of preg_match()

Tags: php

I have a script that is including files when surfer comes from certain websites, it looks like this:

```
<?php
$referral = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (preg_match('/yahoo.com\/main.html|yahoo.com\/secound.html/', $referral)) {
require_once ('a.php');
} else if (preg_match('/google.com/', $referral)) {
require_once ('b.php');
} else {
require_once ('c.php');
}
?>
```

But it is killing my server and I want to replace it with strops() but I do not know how, I tried this:

```
<?php
$referral = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (strops('/yahoo.com\/main.html|yahoo.com\/secound.html/', $referral)) {
require_once ('a.php');
} else if (strops('/google.com/', $referral)) {
require_once ('b.php');
} else {
require_once ('c.php');
}
?>
```

But it's not working :(

Comment: What is this `strops` you speak of ?

Comment: strpos() doesn't use regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$referral = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if ((strpos($referral, 'yahoo.com/main.html')!==false)
  ||(strpos($referral, 'yahoo.com/secound.html')!==false)) {
require_once ('a.php');
} else if (strpos($referral, 'google.com')!==false) {
require_once ('b.php');
} else {
require_once ('c.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: Also may be not a bad idea to use stripos instead. It is case-independent, who knows which case you'll get in referer header...

Answer (score 0):

Look at the PHP documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Strpos finds a particular string in another string, so you can't use regex. You can just find a particular string.

e.g

`strpos('google.com', $referral')`

would return `true` for any strings containing `google.com`. If you wanted to detect multiple different strings you could combine multiple strpos together (with an or operator), or stick with your current approach.

Comment: Thanks. Can I do something like that strpos('google.com\/main.html', $referral') or strpos('google.com\/main.html|yahoo.com\/two.html', $referral') ?

Comment: You can do something like this:

`if (strpos('google.com', $referal') or strpos('yahoo.com', $referal')) {`, etc. But it's not particularly neat.